Cognito CreateAuthChallenge InvalidLambdaResponseException
I'm trying to implement email OTP based custom authentication flow in Cognito using lambda. For which i have created three lambda functions:

DefineAuthChallenge
CreateAuthChallenge
VerifyAuthChallenge

When the flow executes CreateAuthChallenge lambda i'm getting below error in response:
An error occurred (InvalidLambdaResponseException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Unrecognizable lambda output

Cloudwatch Logs:
output: 
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "ap-south-1",
    "userPoolId": "ap-south-1_XXXXXXX",
    "userName": "user@gmail.com",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CreateAuthChallenge_Authentication",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "f113dd3a-1021-7084-2495-8c4eb4853463",
            "email_verified": "True",
            "custom:login-path": "https://ui.test.net",
            "cognito:user_status": "CONFIRMED",
            "name": "user",
            "email": "user@gmail.com"
        },
        "challengeName": "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE",
        "session": [],
        "userNotFound": false
    },
    "response": {
        "publicChallengeParameters": {},
        "privateChallengeParameters": {
            "OTP": "6217"
        },
        "challengeMetadata": {
            "CODE": "CODE-6217"
        }
    }
}


I got it working by changing the response to:
"response": {
    "publicChallengeParameters": {
        "otpLength": 4,
        "email": "user@gmail.com"
    },
    "privateChallengeParameters": {
        "secretLoginCode": "6679"
    },
    "challengeMetadata": "Please enter OTP"
}

Basically, publicChallengeParameters shouldn't be null or empty.
